# How to control parameters accuracy of a function in Python

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have this function in Python:

```
def Rotate_Vector(vector, axis, direction):
```

where **vector** is a tuple of 3 elements (each element represent the three coordinates x,y,z of the vector on Cartesian axes), **axis** are the coordinates of an axis, and **direction** is an integer representing the clockwise or counter-clockwise movement.

I want to control, in my funcion, if the input parameters are correctly:

- *vector* must be a tuple of 3 integer
- *axis* must be a tuple of 3 integer, and the possibile value should be -1, 0, 1
- *direction* must be an integer with value +1 or -1.

I would like to know the right way to do these controls (types, values and numbers of elements) in a function.

Edit:

**axis** could be 6 possibile cases: (1,0,0) (-1,0,0) (0,1,0) (0,-1,0) (0,0,1) (0,0,-1)

Comment: @bobek How do *you* test that *other people* don't pass in a string, a list of file handles and a llama?

Comment: @delnan You don't. It's python, it's duck-typed. Write good documentation and let them do what they want.

Comment: @Lattyware Precisely. Hence I wondered and asked what bobek (who now removed the comment I refer to) would write a test for.

Comment: @delnan Ah, I see, sorry, I misunderstood what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said previously, python is duck typed, thus you simply do things as you normally would, and expect the user to deal with any exceptions raised.

It's better just to unit-test your code, making sure everything works with valid numbers, which increases your confidence in certain things working, and allows you to more easily narrow down possible error locations.

If you really want to check the type, you could use an assertion on the type of the objects (e.g. `isinstance(direction, int)`) for debugging purposes, but this is really just the "poor man's unit test".

Using python's principles (*ask for forgiveness, not permission*, and *explicit is better than implicit*), I would do something like this:

```
import math

def rotate_vector(vector, axis, direction):
    try:
        x, y, z = vector
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("Invalid vector {0}".format(vector))

    valid_axes = {(1,0,0), (-1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,-1,0), (0,0,1), (0,0,-1)}

    if not axis in valid_axes:
        raise ValueError("Invalid axis {0}".format(axis))

    try:
        ax, ay, az = axis
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("Invalid axis {0}".format(axis))

    # do math to rotate the vector
    # rotated = ...

    try:
        # You really only need the sign of the direction
        return math.copysign(rotated, direction)
        # or:
        return rotated * math.copysign(1, direction)
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError("Invalid direction {0}".format(direction))
```

Since you really only care about the sign of direction, you can just use that and eliminate any error checking for it.  The special case of `0` will be treated as `1`, which you may want to raise a `ValueError` for.

If you don't actually need ax/ay/az or x/y/z, it may be better just to directly perform operations on `vector` and `axis`, and let the underlying operations raise the exceptions.  This will enable it for duck typing.

Edit: (updated `axes` -> `axis` for the new values in the question)

Comment: Doing ``type(x) == some_type`` is a _really bad_ way of doing something _bad_. If you __have__ to typecheck, use [``isinstance()``](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance), at least that way you handle inheritance.

Comment: That's a good point, I was only really including it as an example for assertion checking and I should have given a more useful/better example.  Updating this.

Comment: I edit the question for the acceptable parameters for the *axis*

Comment: I updated the answer for your updated axis, though some changes of values isn't really an update you would need to make in your question.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand this last comment.

Comment: You probably shouldn't update your question for something very minor, like the updated values for what a valid axis is.  It's a change you can make in your code, and when you've already got answers posted, it can cause downvotes for invalid reasons.  In other words: your question is answered in its essential form: if the values are bad, raise an exception.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is: don't. Python is duck typed, so just do what you need to, and if it doesn't work, then it'll go wrong.

For example, if you limit vector to a length 3 tuple, then what about the person who passes in a list? If it does the same job, why does it matter to you what they pass in?

If you really feel you need to, then do something like this:

```
if direction not in {1, -1}:
    raise ValueError("direction must be +1 or -1")

if not len(vector) == 3:
    raise ValueError("vector must contain 3 values")
```

etc...

However, this violates Python's principle of *ask for forgiveness, not permission*.

I would also note a better option here is to avoid using magic numbers. Add, for instance, `Vector.FORWARD = +1` and `Vector.BACKWARD = -1` and then tell people to pass those into direction. This still gives flexibility, but gives people guidance as to what to use for direction. Again, you could provide [`namedtuples`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for vectors to provide guidance when constructing them.

It's also worth noting that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advises `lowercase_with_underscores` for function names, so `Rotate_Vector()` isn't a particularly good function name unless you are forced by existing convention in a project.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

...and you suggest me to write _RotateVector()_ instead using **_** ??

Comment: No, he suggests you write `rotate_vector()`, all lower-case but using an underscore to separate words.  Please read PEP-8; he gave you a clickable link.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid checking the type of containers that users send in. As other answerers have noted, this places useless limitations on your code and hence prevents code re-usability. Think of it in terms of interfaces. So long as the arguments conform to the interfaces then the code should work on them and produce required results.

This logic does not apply to two particular constraints that you would like to impose however. Specifically, you want the `axis` variable's entries to lay in `{1, 0, -1}` and you want the direction variable to lay in `{1, -1}`.

These are valid constraints. I would implement them like this:

```
valid_axis_entries = set((1,0, -1))
valid_direction_values = set((1, -1))

def rotate_vector(vec, axis, direction):
    if not all(entry in valid_axis_entries for entry in axis):
        raise SomeErrorCondition

    if direction not in valid_direction_values:
        raise SomeOtherErrorCondition
```

The general rule that I follow is to allow any input which makes sense to fly and `raise` an error on any input which doesn't make sense. Any sequence makes sense for a vector but, depending on your algorithm, not any sequence values make sense for your axis of rotation and `itertools.islice` is certainly not valid input for the direction. Detecting conditions that you know will cause your algorithm to fail and raising useful error messages is as considerate to the users of your code as allowing them to send in anything that does make sense.

Also, I second the suggestion that you store the direction arguments as named variables in upper case and encourage the user to send in those rather than relying on magic constants.

Comment: Python 2.7 and on (which is 90% of python use) have set literals, so you can just do ``{1, 0, -1}``.

Comment: @Lattyware, thanks. I'm on 3 now and I love my set literals but I wasn't sure about python 2 subversions.

Comment: So, I "force" the function to have well-typed parameters. Actually, no external user (except to me) can insert something wrong in this funcion. I mean this is a generic function and I need to rotate just a vector. Then I call the function in another one. This is a Rubik's cube project, so, nobody could insert a bad input form stdin. My doubts come from because in C I always do parameters control, and this thing in Python is new for me. I hope you understand what I want to mean. Thanks for suggets!

Comment: @Kyrol. Python is is dynamically typed. It doesn't know that there's a type error until code treats one type like another. As long as all operations are defined on an object, there won't be a type error. By "user", I meant whoever calls the function you're writing. Generally, it could be you in fifteen months. The difference with C is that C is statically typed so the compiler knows the type of the objects when the code is being compiled. Good luck with the permutation groups.